# What is the most paranoid way to exchange messages?

Tags: encryption

I'm looking for a way for Alice to send a message or a file to Bob in the most paranoid way possible (over the internet).

It can be asymmetric or symmetric. But According to some articles, AES 128bit, RSA, ECC are all broken or will be soon (with the new NSA Utah center).

I found PHPECC library on GitHub: https://github.com/mdanter/phpecc but I don't know how to generate private keys and change key length.

RSA is slow to get a decent security... AKA 2048-bit or more.

AES-256bit is fast and secure with a strong password... but I cannot figure how to communicate the password in the most paranoid way. (Again, please, not on a piece of paper :))

I've made a couple of schemas on a sheet, but I'm sure there's a better way than what I've imagine.

Any help or explanation, or good methods how to do that will be greatly appreciate.

**EDIT:**

OpenSSL Vulnerability: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/03/04/severe_openssl_vulnerability/

AES 128-bit: http://threatpost.ca/en_us/blogs/rsa-2010-experts-expect-several-ciphers-be-cracked-soon-030210

NSA is promoting ECC over RSA. And ECC 112-bit is broken:
http://www.nsa.gov/business/programs/elliptic_curve.shtml

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography

Comment: Why would AES or ECC be broken soon? ECC gets broken by a large quantum computer, but those probably won't appear any time soon. When using classical computers, even the NSA won't be able to afford breaking 256 bit ECC or 128 bit AES for several decades.

Comment: Choosing primitives that withstand classical computers is easy. The hard problem with crypto is always how you distribute public keys without the attacker being able to substitute their own.

Comment: So the public key need to be as much secret as possible? (CodesInChaos: One article here: http://threatpost.ca/en_us/blogs/rsa-2010-experts-expect-several-ciphers-be-cracked-soon-030210)

Comment: A public key doesn't need to be secret. But you need a way to find out which public key belongs to Alice without Eve substituting an evil public key.

Comment: Is this why we need signature? And if it is, how to implement it?

Comment: Public key distribution is a problem that can't be solves purely by cryptography. It boils down to how you define identity. How you do that is application dependent. For example you might print it on your business card.

Comment: Thanks CodesInChaos. And what do you think is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Concerning your articles: 112 bit ECC is broken, but that should be pretty obvious from its security level of 56 bits. ECC with sane sizes, namely 256 bit and above is in no way broken. The only concern is that there are certain patents. | And sorry, you'll need a better article to show the weakness of AES-128 than some vague blog post. I'm not aware of any attack coming close to breaking it in a practical sense.

Comment: Yeah, it's way I wrote "paranoid" hehe. If some are talking about it, it's because it's coming "soon"... but anyway I'll use AES 256 and everything is going to be fine :) To verify identity, any idea? A hash of the key can easily be compromised if Eve is good enough to put her evil key, she's going to be wise enough to change the hash accordigly, right?

Comment: Linking identity to public keys is out of scope for pure crypto. Cryptography can't know who you mean with "Alice". Exchange it in RL, have somebody else you already trust tell you(either web of trust or CA),...

Comment: "Linking identity to public keys is out of scope for pure crypto." Thanks for the tip. I'll try to figure out how to do that. Do you have any good article explaining what is a web of trust and how to implement it? It would be great. thank you for your help.

Comment: Taking your question at face value, obviously the most paranoid way for Alice and Bob to communicate with perfect secrecy is for Bob and Alice to meet somewhere and whisper messages into each others ear.

Comment: Yeah and that's sad :(  Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @JeremyDicaire: Why sad? Maybe they can fall in love, give up cryptography, have a child(Eve?), live happily ever after?(not necessarily in this that order) :-)

Comment: I don't think there is a **most paranoid** way. There are multiple quite good ways, and if you fear that one of them breaks, combine them in a way that all must break for your security goal to be compromised. But paranoid doesn't mean "safe".

Comment: As this is a question with no possible real good answer, I'm closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > RSA is slow to get a decent security... AKA 2048-bit or more.

Well, if you want to be ultra-paranoid, then you'll have to accept some trade-offs.  Suffice to say, a one-time 2048-bit RSA key-exchange shouldn't eat up too much processing time.

Using SSL is the most reliable way to exchange information securely; it not only takes care of the key-exchange and message encryption, but also message authentication (ie, man-in-the-middle attacks).

I don't think you should be concerned about AES being 'broken', but if you really want to be ultra-paranoid, you might take a look at using [Serpent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent_%28cipher%29) - it was the runner-up to Rijndael (AES) in the AES contest, with many people considering it more secure, but slower.

> "Serpent was widely viewed as taking a more conservative approach to security than the other AES finalists, opting for a larger security margin: the designers deemed 16 rounds to be sufficient against known types of attack, but specified 32 rounds as insurance against future discoveries in cryptanalysis."

Comment: Yes I know I need to sacrifice time for more security, unfortunatly hehe. Is Twofish better than serpent? I know it was a finallist for AES too. "it was designed to make the encrypted data is random as possible, so it includes built-in plaintext whitening and other mechanisms that cause it run slower than AES but end with potentially more secure ciphertext." And according to wikipedia, they breaks 11 rounds of the Serpent cipher, but it have 32 rounds, so I'm safe for a while, right?

Comment: Frankly, most people would agree that you'd be safe with either AES, Serpent, or Twofish. They're all excellent algorithms. A lot of articles you might find about 'breaking' these algorithms are usually highly theoretical, and quite often sensationalised.  It's not really helpful to say that 'Twofish is better than Serpent' - it's very unlikely that either will be broken.  Personally I recommend Serpent.  You might find [this](http://superuser.com/questions/207831/which-truecrypt-algorithm-is-the-safest) helpful.

Comment: Something else occurred to me - in light of you mentioning that a 128-bit key wasn't enough (for symmetrical enryption), but that a 2048-bit key for the key exchange (RSA) was too expensive - you might have a look at [this](http://www.keylength.com/en/3/) link.  Keeping in mind that your system is only as strong as the weakest link - you should note that for a 128-bit symmetric key, the equivalent asymmetric key is around 3248 bits. This should put things into perspective.